# Determinant of the change of basis for fractional ideal

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, ideals

Let $A$ be a fractional ideal of some number field extension $K:\Bbb Q$. Let $\omega_1, \dots ,\omega_n$ be a $\Bbb Z$ basis for $\mathcal O_K$ and let $\alpha_1, \dots ,\alpha_n$ be a $\Bbb Z$ basis for $A$. Define a matrix $\bar A = (a_{ij})$ by $\alpha_i = \sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{ij}\omega_j$.

Similarly, let $B$ be the inverse ideal of $A$ with $\Bbb Z$ basis $\beta_1,\dots,\beta_n$ and define $\bar B = (b_{ij})$ by $\beta_i = \sum_{j=1}^{n}b_{ij}\omega_j$.

Is it true that $\bar A\bar B = I_n$ or at the least that $|\det(A)\det(B)|=1$?

The motivation here is to define the norm of a fractional ideal directly as $N(A) = |det(\bar A)|$ without extending it from the normal definition for ideals using unique factorization.

Comment: You can always change $\alpha_1$ to its negative, so the product of the determinants will change its sign. Maybe choosing aligned bases ( http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/alignedbases.pdf ) will help?

Comment: You are correct, I think I only care about it upto sign though. I will take a look at the link, thank you. @darijgrinberg